# How can I power a USB cord from a 12v 2a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, usb, 12v, led-strip, cellphone

I'm new to the forums and have a problem I cannot find an answer to.

I am making a lamp with LED strips inside powered by a 12v 2a power supply.

I want to also power a USB cord with this power supply so I can charge my phone at night.

Is there an easy way of going about this so the same power supply can both power the lights and charge my phone?

Comment: Yes, buy a car 12V usb adapter.

Comment: @Passerby, not "USB adapter", but "USB charger".

Comment: @Ali not charger, power supply, the adapter doesn't charge the phone has the charger internally.

Answer (score 1):

A buck converter is cheap and easy way. There are lots of them on eBay, baggood, amazon, AliExpress any of those sites.

Search for DC to DC converter 12 volt to 5 volt.

Comment: Some even have a USB output connector for the 5V side of things.